# How many times GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT is supposed to be triggered?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

On almost all of my revit models, GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT is triggered only once when I can see the scene as complete. This is what I expect, and when this event is reached, I can do some other actions on the model/view (like moving the complete model to some other coordinates).

But, en a revit model, I have GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT triggered several times, during loading, on model move or zoom in/out.

I can check this by registering a simple
`NOP_VIEWER.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, 
        (e) => {console.log(e)});`

How many times should I expect GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT to be triggered?

Note: On revit file with multiple triggers, I have "onDemandLoad: true" set in the event. It might be the cause. Is there a way to disable this?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

When a model is too large, Forge Viewer may evict certain parts of its geometry from the memory and later load (download) them again when they get back into view. In this case, the `GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT` would be triggered again.

You can disable the memory management by passing 0 as the memory limit in the viewer config. In that case, however, your webpage may run out of memory and get killed off by the browser:

```
const config = {
    memory: {
        limit: 0
    }
};
let viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D(document.getElementById('viewer'), config);
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback, I found info at https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-release-notes-v217 meanwhile. Increasing or disabling memory limit now triggers GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT only once.

Comment: Yep, that's it. Have fun!